# How to change goals after setting up Auto-GPT

Tags: openai-api, gpt-4, autogpt

I have set up Auto-GPT in my system with the goals below.

1 Grow my linkedin account
2 Look for new innovative linkedin post ideas for AI technology
3 Prepare post on that idea
4 Write that post in the file
5 Shutdown

Auto GPT is not producing the results I expected, And now I want to change my goals for different results. How do I modify the goals I set earlier? Or is there any way to improve the result it produces?

I have tried restarting Auto GPT and terminal as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your ai_settings.yaml to change goals.

Comment: Are you able to extract the required from LinkedIn account? If so can you please provide solution for the question that i have posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109998/auto-gpt-getting-counts-of-job-types-in-linkedin