# Auto-GPT : Getting counts of Job Types In LinkedIn

Tags: openai-api, autogpt

I have installed all the packages required to set up Auto-GPT on a Windows Machine. I have configured Auto-GPT as per the installation instructions provided in the [installation](https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT/blob/master/docs/installation.md) page.

My main aim is to set up a goal such that Auto-GPT searches the "LinkedIn" Job website for "Software Engineer", "Senior Software Engineer" and "Software Development" Job Types , get counts of each of these Job Types and return a report of it.

I have setup the following goals in the settings file of the project in order to get the required results but Auto-GPT is not able to get the results of these Job types.

1. Search LinkedIn for "Software Engineers" Job Type and get counts of it.
2. Further search LinkedIn having "Senior Software Engineers" Job Type and get counts of it.
3. Also search for "Software Development" Job Type in LinkedIn and get counts of it.
4. Save the job types along with their counts in a text document.
5. Shutdown

Can you please suggest regarding the process/steps to be followed such that Auto-GPT provides us the count of these Job types from LinkedIn account?